# Parent Child Relationship - SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I used the query in Section A to achieve the screenshot in Section B. But what I actually want to do is shown in Section C.

Section A:

```
SELECT 
    Id, DepartmentName, 
    CAST(0 AS INT) AS 'ParentID',
    CAST(DepartmentName AS VARCHAR(1000)) AS ' '
FROM Departments
WHERE ParentID = 0
UNION ALL

SELECT 
   t2.Id, t2.DepartmentName, t2.ParentID,
   CAST(g.DepartmentName + ' > ' + t2.DepartmentName AS VARCHAR(1000))
FROM Departments t2
INNER JOIN Departments g ON t2.ParentID = g.Id
```

Section B:

[image]

Section C:

[image]

Original Table Output:

[image: Original Table Output:]

Comment: There are a whole bunch of examples on stackoverflow about using Recursive Common Table Expressions (CTEs). Have a quick search for examples.

Comment: @sarin - except most of them refer to Recursive CTEs rather than Hierarchical, since the former term is the one used in the [documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever it was a long night....yep...

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever what do I do to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recursive CTE, almost identical to your existing query:

```
;WITH x as (
SELECT 
    Id, DepartmentName, 
    CAST(0 AS INT) AS 'ParentID',
    CAST(DepartmentName AS VARCHAR(1000)) AS fullname
FROM Departments
WHERE ParentID = 0

UNION ALL

SELECT 
   t2.Id, t2.DepartmentName, t2.ParentID,
   CAST(g.fullname + ' > ' + t2.DepartmentName AS VARCHAR(1000))
FROM Departments t2
INNER JOIN x g ON t2.ParentID = g.Id
)
SELECT * FROM x
```

Comment: Yeah, but I need modifications to achieve Section C:

Comment: Did you try running it? I don't have your data so can't actually F5 it, but it seems OK to me.

Comment: I just added the original table output.